# Swift Gives error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0) when accessing NSManagedObject's property

Tags: swift, core-data, exc-bad-access

My function to create NSManagedObject's subclass object is;

```
func loginMoldelWithName(name: NSString, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> LoginModel {

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("LoginModel", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)

    var login = LoginModel(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext)

    login.name = name
    login.date = NSDate()
    login.rowIndex = indexPath.row as NSNumber

    var error: NSError?
    if !managedObjectContext!.save(&error) {
        println("\(TAG) Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }

    return login as LoginModel
```

}

And the one to delete;

```
func deleteLoginModel(loginModel: LoginModel) {
    println("\(TAG)  \(loginModel.name)")
    managedObjectContext?.deleteObject(loginModel)

    var error : NSError?
    if(managedObjectContext!.save(&error) ) {
        println("\(TAG) \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

And where the issue occurs is at;

```
let loginModel = loginModels[indexPath.row] as LoginModel
println("\(TAG) \(loginModel.name)")
// remove from Core Data
deleteLoginModel(loginModel)
...
```

After removing loginModel object when i try to access the loginModel.name, i'm getting the error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)"

Invalid expression is written for loginModel in the variables view, see the snaphsot below...

I can't find where i did wrong and what could have happened to the loginModel instance ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot you attached, it looks like the error is occurring because you are trying to access the property of an object *after* that object has been deleted. At that point, the properties of the object will no longer be valid memory addresses.

Comment: loginModel is the variable kept in loginModels array...
"let loginModel = loginModels[indexPath.row] as LoginModel"

I think that i just deleted the data in core data, not from array. When i print the array's content after deleting, it prints the LoginModel object with related memory address such as "loginModels[3] (PasswordLockerSwift.LoginModel) 0x00007f92d9d4bc60 0x00007f92d9d4bc60". However i can't access its name property though.

Comment: Because it's still in the array, the loginModel instance still has a memory address. However, because the underlying Core Data object has been deleted, all of the object's properties are now invalid.

Comment: How to check if an instance of coredata object is invalid?